# Does increased starting salary apply to me?

Tags: salary

I am in my final year at university and have a position at a company with a start date of next year.

I heard today that the company is now increasing the base salary for new starts in the same position that I will be in - higher than the salary stated on my offer letter. Will the increase in salary apply to me too?

Comment: Company-specific.  Did you try mailing the HR?

Comment: Hi Sumant, welcome to The Workplace! Unfortunately, your question is likely going to be closed as [off-topic since it is about company-specific policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694). That's not something that any of us here are going to know the answer to, and not something that will be likely useful to future visitors of this site.

Answer (score 10):

> Does the increase in salary applies for me too since i have already
>   got the offer letter and the salary in the offer letter is not the
>   increased one?

Probably not.

You were offered a particular salary and accepted it. What they do in the future is not really relevant.

But **if you want to know for sure, the only way to find out is to ask the people who can give you a definitive answer**. In this case, the hiring manager or whoever sent the offer letter would be the right point of contact.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Joe Strazzere said but I also want to add that, generally speaking, it is not a great idea to compare your salary with that of others you are currently working with. There are all kinds of reasons why someone else may be making more money than you, some of which you are not going to want to hear (for instance, it's entirely possible that one of these people simply interviewed better, or else they increased their standard job offer in order to lure them away from a competitor).

This isn't to say you should just take whatever your employer gives you. If you are informed about how much money people are making in your line of work and know that people with your level of experience are making more than you are, then this is a pretty valid thing to raise. If they're unresponsive, then this is information you can use as well - they may be telling you they don't value you enough to keep you at a competitive rate.

The other point here to note is that small differences in really in my experience don't amount to much in a paycheck and can sometimes even be a little bit of an albatross when an HR department is told that layoffs need to be made or what have you. And this may be a bit on the Pollyanna side but it's also my experience that sometimes it's very valuable to take on a slightly lower salary to get your foot in the door, prove your worth, and then see the amount rise as your employers take notice.